# ¿Para que se usa return 0; en C++?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Muy buenas, estoy llevando a cabo un curso de programación en C++ desde 0 y desde el primer capitulo me han inculcado la "Buena practica" de incluir return 0; al final de cada aplicacion, pero no se que utilidad tiene incluir esta línea, si me pudieran explicar un poquito o derivarme a algún articulo, seria maravilloso.
Muchas gracias, atentamente un novato del C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso se hace para que al regresar el control al sistema operativo, este sepa si hay error o no.

Return 0 indica que no hubo error y 1 que lo hubo, sin embargo puede retonar otros valores.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/return-0-vs-return-1-in-c/

Estos son los llamados códigos de salida que indican el estatus del programa al salir:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exit-codes-in-c-c-with-examples/

Answer (score 1):

El return 0 se utiliza para indicar que el programa se ha ejecutado de manera exitosa. Cualquier otro valor sugiere que ha ocurrido un error.

Cabe notar que puedes omitir el return 0 de la función main, y este aun así será el valor que se retornará por defecto.

Esto puede ser útil cuando, por ejemplo, ejecutes el programa con un script y desees saber si se ejecutó correctamente.